# Two numbers sum to the third

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

Given an array of integers `[a1 a2 ... an]`, not necessarily distinct, give an algorithm that returns "yes" if there are **distinct** indices `i,j,k` such that `ai + aj = ak`, and "no" otherwise.

Is there a way to do this faster than brute force, which takes O(n^3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- build a list of all possible sums ai + aj: O(n^2).
  The list wil have size=n^2
- then compare that list with the array, to see whether there are any similarities:

  - first sort each list: O((n^2)log(n^2)) + O(nlogn)
  - walk through them to find any matches: O(n^2)

total: O((n^2)log(n^2)) ( = O((n^2)log(n)) per comment from alestanis)

edit: i forgot about the distinct requirement, but that should not change the result.
first, to assure i!=j, just exclude i==j when building the list of all sums in step 1.
second, to assure i!=k and j!=k, tag each sum with its indices i,j, and tag each original value with its index k before sorting.
then in the last step when you find any match, check whether the tagged indices are distinct.

Comment: `O((n^2)log(n^2))` is equivalent to `O((n^2)log(n))`

Comment: Okay, but how do you know the three indices `i,j,k` are **distinct**? (See question)

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is.

First step: you **sort the array**.

Then you go through your indices in a *smart way*. A smart way could be to choose

- a0 + a1
- a0 + a2
- a0 + a3
- ...
- a0 + a(n-1)
- a1 + a(n-1)
- a1 + a(n-2)

*Smart* here means that two consecutive pairs of tested indices must not be too far away from each other.

For the first one, `aO + a1` you find if there is a `k` such that `a0 + a1 = ak` with binary search in `O(logn)`.

For the following ones, given that the tested pair is close to the previous one, this means that if there is a `k'` such that `ai + aj = ak'` then `k'` must be close to `k`. You can probably get away with linear search from `k` until your `k'` matches or becomes too big/small for the `ai + aj` pair. This costs `O(1)` in the average case.

As you must tests `n^2` pairs at most, the whole algorithm is `O(n^2)`.

Comment: There's an n^2 solution that doesn't require sorting, although it requires n^2 additional space . . .

Answer (score 0):

The following python code implements a method similar to that stated by alestanis, and similar to the quadratic algorithm given in the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM#Quadratic_algorithm) mentioned by Daniel Le. For large uniformly random positive integers, the stated O(n^2) complexity seems to hold.  (The inner search loop that increments k executed, on the average, about (n^2)/4 times.)  Output from a timed sample run under linux on an old AMD Athlon 5000 processor appears first, followed by the code.

```
0.002519    N 50    NN 2500     ops 607     NN/ops 4.1186   NN/t 992405.8   Matches 0
0.00752     N 100   NN 10000    ops 1902    NN/ops 5.2576   NN/t 1329794.2  Matches 0
0.035443    N 200   NN 40000    ops 10648   NN/ops 3.7566   NN/t 1128570.5  Matches 2
0.063056    N 400   NN 160000   ops 37403   NN/ops 4.2777   NN/t 2537427.4  Matches 33
0.176328    N 800   NN 640000   ops 163247  NN/ops 3.9204   NN/t 3629595.6  Matches 244
0.729919    N 1600  NN 2560000  ops 658122  NN/ops 3.8899   NN/t 3507238.7  Matches 2062
2.720713    N 3200  NN 10240000     ops 2535751     NN/ops 4.0383   NN/t 3763719.4  Matches 16178
11.07818    N 6400  NN 40960000     ops 10160769    NN/ops 4.0312   NN/t 3697358.2  Matches 128793
```

```py
import random, bisect, time
V, W, N, Nlim = 500, 500000, 50, 6400
while N <= Nlim:
    t0 = time.time()
    U=sorted([random.randint(V,V+W) for i in range(N)])
    bigsum = U[-1]
    U.append(N*W)
    matches = ops = 0
    for i, ai in enumerate(U[:-2]):
        k = bisect.bisect_right(U, ai+U[i+1])
        for j, aj in enumerate(U[i+1:-1]):
            while ai+aj > U[k]:
                k += 1
                ops += 1
            if U[k] == ai+aj:
                #print 'Match', i, j, k, ai, aj, ai+aj, U[k]
                matches += 1
            if ai+aj > bigsum:
                break
    et = time.time() - t0
    print round(et,6), '\tN',N, '\tNN', N*N, '\tops', ops, '\tNN/ops',
    print round(float(N*N)/ops,4), '\tNN/t', round(N*N/et,1), '\tMatches', matches
    N *= 2
```

The code probably should be rewritten following the wikipedia outline; a rewrite might clean up some of the awkward array-slice numbers and extraneous completion checks.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

bool SUM3(vector<int> &v)
{
  sort(v.begin(), v.end());

  for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
    int j = 0, k = v.size() - 1;

    while (j < k) {
      int result = v[j] + v[k] - v[i];

      if (result < 0 || i == j) ++j;
      else if (result > 0) --k;
      else return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}

int main()
{
  int a1[] = {25, 7, 9, 2, 4, 8, 10};
  vector<int> v1(a1, a1 + sizeof a1 / sizeof a1[0]);

  printf("%s\n", SUM3(v1) ? "true" : "false");

  int a2[] = {1, 2, 4};
  vector<int> v2(a2, a2 + sizeof a2 / sizeof a2[0]);

  printf("%s\n", SUM3(v2) ? "true" : "false");
  return 0;
}
```

The complexity of this algorithm is O(n ^ 2).